# Inserting an iframe into the bottom of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'm trying to insert an `iframe` using jQuery into a `div`, which the below code does but it deletes all the content in the `div#off`. How do I get the `iframe` to set at the bottom of the content in the `div#off` instead of deleting all the content? Is it possible?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#off").html("<iframe src='http://images.findel-education.co.uk/EmailSignup/website_email_sign_up.html'>></iframe>");  
});
```

I have no control over the parent window so that's why I have to do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.html()` will replace all current HTML markup of your elements, you want to use **[.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** instead:

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element
>   in the set of matched elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#off").append("<iframe src='http://images.findel-education.co.uk/EmailSignup/website_email_sign_up.html'>></iframe>");  
});
```

Comment: No worry! Glad you learn something new :) Happy coding mate :-)